# google drive integration v3 in php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Hi Im trying Google drive integration v3 in php to upload file from my web page i do not want to use picker. I have successfully done oauth and login. I can create a file in the drive but with empty data. the error i get is permission to write i have given public access to that folder. How can i solve this and write the content to that file.

My code after auth(successfull) redirect.

first.php

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('conf/client_id.json');
//$scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_APPDATA);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$data = file_get_contents("a.png");
// create and upload a new Google Drive file, including the data
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile($client);
$file->setName('img_'.uniqid().'.png');
$file->setMimeType('image/png');

 //$parent = new Google_ParentReference();
//$parent->setId("0B687nRLFFN08ZXg0WU9Zb3VQaEE");
//$file->setParents(array($parent));
//$file->setParents(array('setId'=>"0B687nRLFFN08ZXg0WU9Zb3VQaEE"));

$createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
'data' => file_get_contents("a.png"), //$data
'mimeType' => 'image/png',
'uploadType' => 'media'
));

} 
else {
   $redirect_uri='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/google/oauth2callback.php';
header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear you cant programmatically write to a file using the Google Drive API.   The file must contain its data when uploaded.

Comment: its a image file (a.png) i have got the file contents in $data and passing it in the array $service->file->create

Comment: Can u help me in this solution once the file is created how to pass data to that file in google drive.

Comment: As I said you cant write to a file programmatically you need to upload a new file containing the data.

Comment: if im not wrong in v2 the example which they give has $data = file_get_contents("a.png"); containing the local upload file data then write it to the new file created in the drive.